# Let $f(n)$ be the number of simple undricted graphs with $n$ vertices numbered ${1,2,\dots,n}$ s.t every vertex degree is 2.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $f(n)$ be the number of simple undricted graphs with $n$ vertices numbered ${1,2,\dots,n}$ s.t every vertex degree is 2.

Find a recurrence relations for $f(n)$

**My attempt:**

Since that the degree of every vertex is $2$, the number of vertices is at least $3$. Now there are two possible options for the $n^{th}$ vertex location:

- In a circle of 4 or more vertices.
- In a circle of excatly 3 vertices.

The first option is quite easy - $(n-1)f(n-1)$.
In the second option, I need to choose the other 2 vertices $\binom{n-1}{2}$. Now I'd like to multiply it by $f(n-3)$ but I don't think I can, since $f(n)$ is defined by the vertices numbered ${1,2,\dots,n}$. And if, for intance, the vertices numbered 1 and 3 are in a circle with the $n^{th}$ one, it's not $f(n-3)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

( **Note** that joriki's answer is more to the point, and leads to the simpler recursion
$$f(n)=(n-1)f(n-1)+{n-1\choose2}f(n-3)\ .\quad)$$
The graphs $\Gamma$ in question are disjoint unions of cycles $\Gamma_i$ of length $r_i\geq3$.

For the induction you cannot just throw in the vertex $v_n$ into an existing cycle. Instead you have to build the full cycle containing $v_n$.

One has $f(0)=1$, $\>f(1)=f(2)=0$, $\>f(3)=1$.

For $n\geq4$ we argue as follows: Vertex $v_n$ is in a cycle of length $r\in[3..n]$. This cycle can be chosen in
$$(n-1)(n-2)\cdots\bigl(n-(r-1)\bigr)/2$$
ways, whereby the $/2$ accounts for the the idea that the graphs $\Gamma_i$ should be nondirected. After the cycle containing $v_n$ has been chosen there are $n-r$ vertices left which then can be arranged in $f(n-r)$ ways to undirected cycles. Summing it up we obtain the recursion
$$f(n)=\sum_{r=3}^n {(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-r+1)\over2} f(n-r)\qquad(n\geq4)\ .$$
One obtains
$$\bigl(f(n)\bigr)_{n\geq0}=(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 12, 70, 465, 3507, 30016, 286884,\ldots)\ .$$
This is sequence [A001205](http://oeis.org/A001205) at OEIS.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're quite right to multiply by $f(n-3)$. You've already accounted for the fact that you can choose the $2$ vertices that form a triangle with $n$ in $\binom{n-1}2$ ways. Whatever $n-3$ vertices remain can form an admissible graph in $f(n-3)$ ways, no matter what their specific labels are.